# Doing a simple Form validation using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to do form validation to check against empty forms, I am using jquery for that.

I have this code - everything works fine, but i want it to verify the data in forms that its not empty. The error is here

```
if(u == '' || p ==''){
  alert('Please Enter all Data Correctly');
  return false;
}
```

How do i get to do a simple form validation using Jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var u = $('#u').val();
    var p = $('#p').val();

    if (u == '' || p == '') {
      alert('Please Enter all Data Correctly');
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/index.php",
      data: {
        u: u,
        p: p
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
          window.location.replace("https://mmm.xxxx");
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: To work with the `event` object inside your handler, it needs to have an `event` parameter in its signature.

Comment: @connexo can u show me

Comment: It has to be `$("#my_form").submit(function(event) {` in your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.